# Как убрать формат документа в домене

Tags: javascript, php, html, site

Всем привет! Не подскажите как убрать в строке домена формат документа при переходе по силке?

Было site.ru/index.html нужно site.ru/index

Comment: где конкретно убрать?

Comment: Можно через .htaccess RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта история не имеет отношения ни к PHP, ни к JS. Хотя если Вы используете какие-то готовые системы типа Битрикса, там эта адресация может быть вшита и нужны другие методы.

Но в общем виде это зависит на чем у Вас сервер

На SOF уже обсуждались эти темы, например

Nginx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228393/nginx-remove-html-extension

Apache https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url

Answer (score 0):

Просто создай папку index, в неё закинь index.html